# Viewed but un-actioned flags are not faded in the queue on Opera

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, opera

If a moderator views a flag on a post, but doesn't act upon it, the post will subsequently be faded when the flag queue is viewed. For example, this is how it looks in Chrome (Firefox is the same):

[image: Chrome screenshot]

On Opera 12.02 (Windows 7), the fading does not occur:

[image: Opera screenshot]

I'm not sure if this affects other sites, but my guess is that it might. It also appears to affect the 10k flag queue list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason Opera doesn't like opacity on the `<tr>` there, I've moved it to the relevant `<td>` which fixes display.

This will go out with the next build.

Comment: The fading does appear to be fixed, but mousing over a faded post in the flag queue no longer seems to un-fade it (on any browser).

Comment: @eldarerathis - that'll be fixed in the next build.